# Unable to navigate page with inertia-link if route is dynamic

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I cant find a way to navigate to a new page when inertia-link is clicked when using a dynamic route in laravel.

route:

```
 This two is not added together in the code. I tried both way to tested so i put both here
 Route::get('/{clothesCategory}', 'ClothesController@getCalsas'); // this doesnt work
 Route::get('/NotDynamic, 'ClothesController@getCalsas'); // this work
```

Html:

```
<inertia-link href="/NotDynamic">Not Working</inertia-link> //this only works with NotDynamic route
<a href="/NotDynamic">Working</a> // this works with both routes
```

Why is this happening I dont understand the reason behind it? also how can I get the inertia-link to work with the Dynamic route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to do this using `:headers`

```
 <inertia-link href="/endpoint" :headers="{ clothesCategory: endpoint}">end point</inertia-link>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply follow this example:

```
<inertia-link :href="'/' + data.slug">Go To</inertia-link>
```

use the ":" (colon symbol) before "href". Then you can insert dynamic value into the link.